# Comparing columns between tables

Tags: c#, data-comparison

I have 10  tables from different  sources that I import  into a SQL Server database. I want to  compare them with  a table named basic_source.
What I want to do is compare each attribute in basic_source with each attribute in the other 10 tables, one at each time. If the  two attributes have same name, then look  at their values (which should be distinct value).  Then, extract the values to an array. The logic I'm looking for is below

Tables{ table1, table2, table3,………., table10}

If (columni name from basic_table  = columnj name from table1)

//Extract data  from columnj to an array 
columnj_value[]=("select distinct (columnej) from table1")

Next columni from basic_table , Next attributej from table1
Next table

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of your question, you could possibly use a [`Dictionary<string, object>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) to represent the column names and values in your table. For example, you would store a `Dictionary<string, object>` object for each table, then when comparing, you could do a look up inside the `KeyValuePair` objects in each `Dictionary`, looking for relevant matches.